# Find pattern in large text file quickly?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file which has a lot of space separated text columns. One column looks like this - 
 where number is 3 or more digits. eg <234>, <9473> etc.

eg.

```
text.... text... <2329> text...
text.... text... <735> text...
text.... text... <23229> text...
text.... text... <2444> text...
```

I only want to find those numbers and print or save the results of the search using bash. How do I do it ?

Thanks

I am doing this using linux [L]ubuntu.

Comment: Write question that is comprehensible easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If column # is not fixed and you just want to capture numbers between `<` and `>` then use:

```
awk -F '[<>]+' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) if ($i ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]+$/) print $i}' file
```

**Using grep -P (perl regex):**

```
grep -oP '(?<=<)\d{3,}(?=>)' file
```

Comment: +1 I did not know you could use something like `-F '[<> ]+'` with awk. Very cool.

Comment: ps. he's looking for numbers 3 digits or more

Comment: @naomik: Oh ok thanks, my grep command should work. I will edit awk command as well.

Comment: @anubhava - sorry but the output file is blank for 1st two commands.

Comment: @anubhava you have tremendous awk abilities.

Comment: @blasto: With your sample input file it does print the numbers in angular brackets. Try suggested grep also. I would suggest you to provide a small snippet of actual input file so that we can suggest you best answer.

Comment: I have also edited my awk command to make it capture any 3 or more digits between angular brackets in the file. grep should also work.

Comment: @anubhava - third script works. Man, you must be a genius. They should have a bowing smiley just for you. I checked my results. Need to improve my bashing skills.

Comment: @anubhava - Just realized how much this perl regex helps. Is there a chance that perl regex will not work on some systems ? I ask this because I think that bash and perl are different things.

Comment: @anubhava - I figured out everything. In the GREP answer, what does this mean - (?<=<) and (?=>) --- ? I understand what it does, but how does it work ?

Comment: This is actually called look ahead and look behind. Both are positive look arounds. `(?<=<)` is positive look behind which means that 3 digits are preceded by <. Whereas `(?=>)` is positive look ahead which means 3 digits should be followed by a single >.

Answer (score 3):

This will find all lines which contain 3 digits or more in `your_file`, then output the number

```
$ grep -P "<\d{3,}>" your_file | awk -F'[<> ]+' '{print $3}'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Given this file

```
text.... text... <1> text...
text.... text... <2329> text...
text.... text... <735> text...
text.... text... <23229> text...
text.... text... <2444> text...
```

Output

```
2329
735
23229
2444
```

Comment: please see my edit. I only want to look for numbers that are between <> brackets. Also, grep will show all text and highlight matches. I only want the found numbers. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually avoid piping to awk and use `-o` switch in grep to capture the matched string.

Comment: naomik - my output is delimiter multiple times ?

Comment: @anubhava, yeah I saw that in your post. Very nice :)

Comment: @naomik - thanks for your help. BTW, how did you make such a nice diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

Since grep and awk are already taken, you can use sed :)

```
sed -rn 's/.*<([0-9]{3,})>.*/\1/p' FILE
```

Comment: does not work. there is another column which has only <42> everywhere. The column which I need has 3 numbers or more.

Comment: You can change the pattern to: `.*<([0-9]{3,})>.*`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was struggling with that.  Tried \{3\} and other permutations.  Missed yours.

Comment: @SeanMcLaughlin - text file has 8096 rows that match criteria. Your code only returned 7510. Last row in your output is 20, but 20 is not there anywhere in my text file.

Comment: + was unnecessary, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: Actually this sed regex can't work because of presence of multiple target 3+ digits on each line. If you note this will just capture **last match** from each line.

Comment: @anubhava  Is it possible to fix easily with sed?  -o did it nicely for grep.

Comment: That won't be easily possible in sed since sed doesn't support lookarounds  as does the grep -p (Perl regex)